# Create advanced search

Tags: 7, search

I currently use search api solr and facetapi to filter jobs on my website.

I now want to create an advanced search on a different page using the same taxonomy as I use with facetapi on my jobpage.

I've tried creating a facetblock but once I click a taxonomy term it directly goes to my job page, I want to be able to select multiple things, press search (much like exposed filters does), and redirect to my job page.

Thanks